# How to get filenames in a folder 1 by 1 and use them in .txt file

Tags: c#

Is this possible? What im trying to do here is get file names from a directory then use those file name in a text file removing existing text replacing with file name. The problem i having is filename1 replaces all oldtext in file I just need 1 filename per oldtext in the .txt file

oldtext? = text in .txt i want to replace with file name

ex.

1. Replace oldtext1 with filename1
2. Replace oldtext2 with filename2
3. Replace oldtext3 with filename3

   and so on

Alphabetical order would be ideal.

Thankx in advance.

.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] Files1 = dinfo1.GetFiles("*.*");

string text = File.ReadAllText("path/text.txt");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files1)
{
    text = text.Replace("oldtext1", "path" + file.Name);
    text = text.Replace("oldtext2", "path" + file.Name);
    text = text.Replace("oldtext3", "path" + file.Name);

}

File.WriteAllText("path/text.txt", text)
```

;

Comment: So? What's stoping you? you already have the `FileInfo` array, that can be sorted either by using linq or by creating a comparer, and you have the text = `text.replace...` - So where is the problem, really?

Comment: The problem is it doesnt move to filename2 it replace all oldtext1, oldtext2, oldtext3 with filename1

Comment: What if you have more files then strings to replace? or more strings to replace then files?

Comment: its not possible. The folder files are pics and the file is a .dvds converted to a .text. I use a program to build the .dvds based of the number of files in the folder but it dont embed the photos so im creating a program that embed the photo to the .dvds so when it is build th photo are on the .dvds files. I hope you can understand what im saying.

Comment: So if you delete all file and add a new file your .txt would contain for exemple 8 file name and 1 file at the first spot.   This would lead to a good name and 7 names not valid.  Is it really what you want ?

Comment: no the .dvds would be rebuild and will only need the 1 filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code replaces all texts inside the loop, with the same file name, so after the loop is done, all your oldtexts should contain the last file name.

You should do something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] Files1 = dinfo1.GetFiles("*.*");
string[] StringsToReplace = {"oldtext1", "oldtext2", "oldtext2"};
string text = File.ReadAllText("path/text.txt");


for(int i=0; i < StringsToReplace.Length; i++)
{
    if(i >= Files1.Length)
    {
        break;
    }
    text = text.Replace(StringsToReplace[i], "path" + Files1[i].Name);   
}

File.WriteAllText("path/text.txt", text);
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! Thanks alot it works just how i pictured it. You are the man Zohar